# Modifying headers for repeated row values?

Tags: r

For example, this is my data:

```
age     gender       education                   previous_comp_exp   tutorial_time 
19      Male         Undergraduate               casual gamer        37.93436 
qID     time_taken   time_to_first_interaction   num_of_interactions answered_correctly 
sor0    26.27869     14.82285                    4                   TRUE 
sor5    23.53426     7.422562                    8                   TRUE 
sor4    24.84502     10.41148                    4                   TRUE
```

I want to convert to this:

```
age     gender       education                   previous_comp_exp   tutorial_time      qID.1       time_taken.1     time_to_first_interaction.1     num_of_interactions.1  answered_correctly.1    qID.2       time_taken.2     time_to_first_interaction.2     num_of_interactions.2  answered_correctly.2    qID.3       time_taken.3     time_to_first_interaction.3     num_of_interactions.3 answered_correctly.3
19      Male         Undergraduate               casual gamer        37.93436           sor0        26.27869         14.82285                        4                       TRUE                   sor5        23.53426         7.422562                        8                      TRUE                    sor4        24.84502         10.41148                        4                     TRUE
```

So in summary, I want row 3 to be a repeated and number of times and added to the headers. And secondly, I want each row entry below row 3 to be moved to the first row under the corresponding repeated column.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: @akrun, what about the 3rd row which as the differing headers? How do I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `dcast` from row 3 onwards with column names as row 2

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setNames(df1[3:nrow(df1),], unlist(df1[2,]))
setDT(df2)[, ind := 1]
r1 <- dcast(df2, ind ~ rowid(ind), 
      value.var = setdiff(names(df2), 'ind'), sep='.')[, ind := NULL][] 

res <- data.table(df1[1,], r1[, order(as.numeric(sub(".*\\.", "", names(r1)))), with = FALSE])

res
#   age gender     education previous_comp_exp tutorial_time qID.1 time_taken.1 time_to_first_interaction.1 num_of_interactions.1 answered_correctly.1 qID.2
#1:  19   Male Undergraduate      casual gamer      37.93436  sor0     26.27869                    14.82285                     4                 TRUE  sor5
#   time_taken.2 time_to_first_interaction.2 num_of_interactions.2 answered_correctly.2 qID.3 time_taken.3 time_to_first_interaction.3 num_of_interactions.3
#1:     23.53426                    7.422562                     8                 TRUE  sor4     24.84502                    10.41148                     4
#   answered_correctly.3
#1:                 TRUE
```

Comment: This is awesome @arkun. One issue with formating. Would it be possible to group the new headers, for example: qID.1, time_taken.1... qID.2, time_taken.2... etc

Comment: @stenfeio  If you need to order it, then we can do it.  I edited the post

Comment: much thanks! this has taken a lot of my time. I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: i'm trying to understanding how you came up with this: is there a reason you copied the first row into the last?

Comment: @stenfeio  You meant the 'age', 'gender', etc?  As we need only a single row, the first row was taken and created a data.table with the `dcast` values of the other rows into a single row

Comment: @arkun, I'm having a hard time understanding what lines 3, 4, and 5 are doing exactly. Would it be possible to comment?